Is there a solution to the problem with USB DAC?
I have a USB DAC - SMSL SK10 Sanskrit 10th MKIII.
I will indicate the frequency on which I use it on the screenshot.

In most applications and games, this DAC works without any problems at this frequency, but there are two games (sims and Company of Heroes 2) where there is no sound.
If you reduce the frequency in these games (for example, 24 bit and 96 kHz), then the sound appears in these games, but I do not want to constantly reduce the sound because of these two games.
Maybe there is some application or script that allows you to reduce the frequency for specific games and applications when they are launched?
P.S.
I'll add to my question. Why don't I do 24-bit 96kHz all the time?
I just want to get the most out of the device, plus self-hypnosis.

Controlling the sound card settings when launching an app MAY be possible, but could be quite tricky to implement. However I would suggest just running at a lower rate all the time, 24/44.1 would be absolutely fine, it’s the bit/sample rate that is used the majority of commercial recorded music. 32 bit is not well defined and often a floating point system in audio (giving margin for error rather than any quality increase) and 384000hz is so incredibly high I would be surprised if that figure is actually true. Either way we do not need a nyquist of 192khz when our hearing is max 20khz!

Can you edit your question to explain why you don’t just leave the setting on 24-bit 96kHz all the time?

Ok, to your edit, I do sort of get the self hypnosis aspect, however theres a reason that these games don't support it. It's because it's a sound 'quality' level so inordinately high that there is no benefit to using that much bandwidth, a fact that can be easily proved. It's also so high that it's arguable that other aspects of the DAC conversion cannot keep up with it, and you potentially even harm audio quality by forcing a DAC to run at these rates. Even very high end converters have been accused of this. It gets very technical, I'm not sure if I'm willing to deep dive into an...

..explanation when it concerns the output from a game (which would be outputting sound captured at 24bit, 44.1Khz at absolute BEST, most likely some compressed format). You've got the old 'I simply must use a suspiciously rated 16k monitor to view my 100Kb jpegs' issue. It's arguable that 8k is too much (roughly equivalent to 96k audio), 16k is overkill and unlikely to even be possible (roughly 192kHz equivalent in audio sample rate), you're talking about 384KHz, that is just HUGE... HUGE, and unlikely to be real, and doesn't even take into account 32bit being enormous overkill as well.

Another answer might contain a clue on how to do this. https://superuser.com/questions/1701907/change-soundcard-bit-depth-and-sample-rate-via-command-line-in-windows.

Here is a tool that will probably help you do what you are attempting
to do. It is free and written by NirSoft. Look specifically at the
/SetDefaultFormat [Bits Per Sample] [Sample Rate - Hertz] command line
option.

You could possible setup a few command scripts that first changes the settings and then starts the respective game.
(In parenthesis: as others have indicated this does not necessarily give you any better sound. The game probably creates sounds at 48kHz sample rate / 16 bit internally as this is the common standard. This will be uppsampled by an algorithm in the computer before sending it to the DAC. This does not improve objective sound quality but rather detracts from it. But, then again, as often what we perceive is not the objective truth and worse quality sometimes is perceived as better. )
